# How to display more details of a perticular table in a separate page using angularJS and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

[image: This is My database]

[image: This is my html page]

I used ng-repeat and was able to display the data in the database.
I want to display more information of a perticular table when "Know more" button is clicked in a seperate popup page.
how can i achieve this in angularjs ?

```js
.controller('far_req_disp', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('php/far_req_disp.php')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.request = data;
    })
    .error(function() {
      $scope.error = "error";
    });
})
```

```html
<div ng-controller="seller_post_disp">
  <ion-list ng-repeat="a in usr007">
    <h2>{{a.crop_id}}</h2>
    <p>Villiage:{{a.village}} & District :{{a.DIST}}</p>
    <p>Expected Price:{{a.expec_price}} {{a.Per}}</p>

    <p>Date of availability:From {{a.from_date}} To {{a.to_date}}</p>
    <a class="button" ng-click="knowMore()">Know More </a>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass your data object to your knowmore function like this:

```
<a class="button" ng-click="knowMore(a)">Know More </a>
```

1) And Catch that data in your function like:

```
$scope.knowmore = function(data){
    console.log(data); // 
};
```

2) Else if you use in a separate page for details, broadcast your object and catch it like this.

```
$scope.knowmore = function(data){
    $scope.$broadcast('seller_post, data);
};
```

Using $scope.$broadcast will fire an event down the $scope. Using $scope.$on is how we listen for these events. Now you can use it across controllers via catch up the "loadPost" event.

```
// listen for the event in the relevant $scope
$scope.$on('seller_post', function (event, data) {
   console.log(data); 
});
```